# jsoncpp error: ‘PrecisionType’ is not a class or namespace

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, jsoncpp

I download jsoncpp on Github. And built and installed it with meson and ninja. But when I include `<json/json.h>` in my program, I got the error:

> ‘PrecisionType’ is not a class or namespace.

Is there anything wrong in `"json/writer.h"` ?

Error:
[image: error]

Comment: Please add any code or error output to your question. Indent them with four spaces or use the toolbar button to create a code block.

Comment: Please post code in TEXT form. Use the `{}` icon to make it look like code.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are using the example test code from 
https://finbarr.ca/jsoncpp-example/

The issue would be a Makefile problem in the ordering of the flags:

change Makefile from example to look like this:

```
CXX = g++
CPPFLAGS = -std=gnu++11
LDFLAGS = -L/{YOUR_PATH}/jsoncpp/build/debug/src/lib_json -ljsoncpp
INC = -I/{YOUR_PATH}/jsoncpp/include

main: main.cpp
    $(CXX) -o main main.cpp $(CPPFLAGS) $(INC) $(LDFLAGS)
```

Fix your path, but make sure the order of flags is correct...

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to access an enum (PrecisionType is an enum)i.e. `PrecisionType::significantDigits` is compliant to `-std=c++11` and not to older ones

```
/** \brief Type of precision for formatting of real values.
 */
enum PrecisionType {
  significantDigits = 0, ///< we set max number of significant digits in string
  decimalPlaces          ///< we set max number of digits after "." in string
};
```

**Solution**

If you are compiling with just g++ you can add the following `g++ -std=c++11 <file-name>`

If its a `Makefile` you need to edit your CPPFLAGS to `CPPFLAGS= -std=c++11`

Regards,